# Half-precision: Difference between __float2half vs __float2half_rn

Tags: cuda

There seems to be no documentation about these two functions.

What is the difference between `__float2half` and `__float2half_rn`?

Comment: Did you check the [CUDA Math API documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__MISC.html#group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__MISC)? `__float2half()` is documented there. It seems the other one does not exist. Maybe you meant `__float2half2_rn()`?

Comment: E.g. http://karlssonper.github.io/gpuip/api/lerp_8cu-example.html

Comment: I see... And it is actually mentioned in the [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#sixteen-bit-floating-point-textures).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems the CUDA documentation is indeed a bit inadequate here.

The function `unsigned short __float2half_rn(float)` in combination with `float __half2float(unsigned short x)` was already present in CUDA before the new `half` datatype was introduced in CUDA 7.5.
It is defined in `device_functions.h`. The comment there reads:

> Convert the single-precision float value *x* to a half-precision floating point value represented in *unsigned short* format, in round-to-nearest-even mode.

The function `half __float2half(float)` is defined in `cuda_fp16.h` and does apparently the same, but returns a `half`:

> Converts float number *a* to half precision in round-to-nearest mode.

---

However, since `half` is a typedef to `unsigned short`, I checked if they do the same, with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cuda_fp16.h"
#include "device_functions.h"
__global__ void test()
{
//  auto test = __float2half( 1.4232 );
    auto test = __float2half_rn( 1.4232 );
    printf( "%hu\n", test );
}

int main()
{
    test<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

I found that (for `sm_20`) the old `__float2half_rn()` has an additional int16 to int32 operation and does a 32bit store. On the other hand, `__float2half_()` does not have this conversion and does a 16bit store.

Relevant SASS code for `__float2half_rn()`:

```
/*0040*/         I2I.U32.U16 R0, R0;
/*0050*/         STL [R2], R0;
```

For `__float2half()`:

```
/*0048*/         STL.U16 [R2], R0;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed answer.